# How to regex in c++ when there are new lines?

Tags: c++, regex

I need to find repeating numbers in a large file with numbers on each line. I have this:

```
std::regex var_ree(([\\d]+)\\n\\1", std::regex::icase);
```

I've tryed a lot of things, and I get nothing. This is the code I came up with a regex website and it works there, I have no idea why it doesn't work on my program.

Comment: You should show how you are using this regex. Which function are you using to match your file against this regex? And you did miss a `"` in the question.

Comment: While it can certainly be done, I doubt that regex is the appropriate tool for this task.

Comment: You should some some example data and what you expect to match (and maybe not match). Also, if your data has carriage returns (as @Aschab seems to think), also make that clear and let us know if you're running on Windows or Unix and how you're opening the data file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
std::regex var_ree("([\\d]+)\r\n\\1", std::regex::icase);
```

You were missing the first double quote (I assume you misstyped).
You don't need to double scape \n. "\n" is an scaped character for "new line" and you wer emissing "\r" an scaped character for carriage return

Comment: On the \n vs \r\n issue. You should add an an if in the regex to accept either. Depending on your system, \n or \r\n could be the new line syntax.

Comment: Unix doesn't use `\r\n`, nor does text from a file opened in translation mode such as `std::ifstream infile(...);` - you only get `\n` in that case - even under Windows.